# Como cambiar el valor de un booleano a su valor contrario en C++

Tags: c++

Como se puede hacer para que si un booleano esta positivo, pase a negativo y viceversa.

Ya se que se puede hacer de esta manera, pero no me parece practica:

```
function() {
  if (booleano) {
    booleano = false
  } else {
    booleano = true
  }
}
```

Estoy buscando algo como:

```
function {
  booleano * -1
}
```

Comment: booleano = !booleano

Answer (score 4):

el tipo booleano no es más que un valor entero que se ha creado para permitir un código más legible. Este tipo se ha diseñado para encajar perfectamente en los condicionales de C++, donde los resultados de las evaluaciones serían:

- `false` si la evaluación genera un `0`
- `true` si la evaluación genera cualquier otro valor.

Esto es facil de comprobar [enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gYhTlqi7sxhoT2im):

```
for (int i=-5; i<=5; i++)
    if (i) std::cout << i << " es verdadero\n";
```

Así pues, está claro que `false` debe valer 0 mientras que `true`, en principio, podría tener cualquier otro valor. La solución adoptada por el estándar fue asignar 1 al valor `true` ([fuente](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions)):

> If the source type is bool, the value **false is converted to zero** and the value **true is converted to the value one** of the destination type (note that if the destination type is int, this is an integer promotion, not an integer conversion).

Sabiendo ahora los valores de `true` y `false` es facil ver que para pasar de uno a otro nos vale con negarlo:

- `!true  == !1 == 0 == false`
- `!false == !0 == 1 == true`

Así que, respondiendo a tu pregunta, para cambiar el valor de un tipo booleano basta con usar el operador de negación:

```
bool dato = false;

for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    dato = !dato;

    if (dato) std::cout << "true\n";
    else      std::cout << "false\n";
}
```

Comment: Estás confundiendo el operador de comparación con el operador de negación. Es `dato = !dato`.

Comment: @Mateo cierto, no me había dado cuenta, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
function() {
 booleano = !booleano
}
```

Ya que un booleano solo puede tomar dos valores, true o false, adoptará el volor contrario al que tenga es el momento de llamar a la función

Comment: Bienvenido. Gracias por tu aporte. Noto que es muy similar a la otra respuesta. En lugar de *repetir* una respuesta, considera votar a favor las que ya existan.